# cannot find image error after training the model using labelimg

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have trained some images using labelimg.

When i start training the model, it got below error, so i think it is because of the special charachter 'camara' so i renamed this in dataset\train\images and dataset\train\annotations folder.

But the model is still looking for the same image, which is no longer in dataset\train\images folder. Where are these images names are stored, or how to clear the cache.

Please help.

This is the error:

Cannot find  dataset\train\images\7037339-cámara-de-seguridad-sobre-fondo-gris-pared-abstracta-.jpg
Epoch 1/203

Code i have used:

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer
trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory="dataset")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["CC Camera","Nest Cam"],batch_size=4, num_experiments=200)
trainer.trainModel()
```

Runnig using pythonIDLE

Comment: How are people supposed to help you if you do not show any code or commands you ran?

Comment: I added the code now

Answer (score 1):

There will be one **cache** folder created at the directory level, you need to remove that cache folder manually or using `shutil.rmtree()` should resolve your issue.